# Multiple selection in php

Tags: php, html

First I know this question has been asked multiple times but I am asking this again because I have tried the solutions that were given on the previous questions and none has solved my problem.

With the code below I can only select one option at the time and I need to select multiple options and send them to PHP as an array. I'm using chrome version 62.0.xx..

Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="one" action="query.php" method="POST" >
        <select multiple="multiple" name="def[]">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select><br>
        <input type="submit" name="SubIn" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @DawidZbiński Your comment is wrong, you CAN select multiple options of the select tag.

Comment: `i have tried the solutions that were given` I dont see anything you have tried. I only see your markup.

Comment: Press `ctrl key` for selecting multiple options while selecting.

Comment: I've taken it back as I forgot there's multiple attribute, either way, I think what you @Bsn try to approach is better to achieve with checkboxes. It's surely more user-friendly and easier to achieve. As by using select you need to hold some keys (like Ctrl or Cmd) to make it possible to select multiple options.

Comment: Yes it can be done, the thing is why it is not working.
The "problem" Im getting is that i can only select one option at the time and it is supposed to let me select multiple options.

Comment: press ctrl in keyboard and select your choices if you want to use multiple

Comment: @GyandeepSharma this solved the "problem". the question now is there a way to not need to press shift ?

Comment: @Bsn i prefer to use checkbox for multiple choices

Comment: In my knowledge there are some plugins for this like [select2](https://select2.org/). If you want dropdown only..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Ctrl+option` to select multiple selection, press `Ctrl` and select options by mouse click

```js
function changed(elem){
  var select1 = document.querySelector("#def");
    var selected1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < select1.length; i++) {
        if (select1.options[i].selected) selected1.push(select1.options[i].value);
    }
    document.querySelector("#selected").innerHTML = selected1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="one" action="query.php" method="POST" >
        <select onchange="changed(this)" multiple="multiple" name="def[]" id="def">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select><br>
        <input type="submit" name="SubIn" />
    </form>
    <div id="selected"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in below snippet its perfect just select option with holding `ctrl`, hold `ctrl` and select option by mouse click

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="one" action="query.php" method="POST" >
        <select multiple="multiple" name="def[]">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select><br>
        <input type="submit" name="SubIn" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

you can get this options as an array with `$_POST['def']`.